# Migrating to Youtube API 3.0

Tags: youtube-api

I heard Youtube API v2 is deprecating and I want to update my old feed. This json feed gets the recent live youtube event.

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[USER_ID]/live/events?v=2&alt=json-in-script&status=active&orderby=published&callback=onActiveLiveFeeds

changing v2 to v3 didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the equivalent in the new API is the [LiveBroadcasts#list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list). There's some code samples on that page.